# How can I use custom HTML/CSS in the login page?

Tags: 9

I have custom HTML and CSS code for a login page. I want to customize my site's login form to look like the custom login page I have. How can I customize the default login page with the HTML and CSS code I have? All similar questions I saw were either outdated or didn't address this "custom HTML/CSS code" aspect.

Comment: Use Drupal's theme system. Turning on theme debugging will tell you exactly which templates to implement if you are unsure.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom module to use attaching a library to a form

As forms are just render arrays, attaching a library works just the same:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */

    function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
      if ($form_id == 'article_node_form') { {
          $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'yourmodule/yourlibrary';
        }
    }
```

Here is the official documentation with an anchor to the part that explain how to add it to a form : https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-module#s-attaching-a-library-to-a-form